# Does function stack save the return address?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64

I'm learning things about function stack based on assembly using the system Linux x86.

I've read some article, which told me that a function stack (callee) would save the return address where it is called by the caller so that the computer could know the point where to continue when the function returns.

This is why there is a kind of attack: stack smashing.
The stack smashing means that if we can overflow a function stack, especially overflow the return address with a designed address, the program will execute the codes of hackers.

However, today I'm trying to use gdb to check a simple c++ program as below but I can't find any saved return address in any function stack.
Here is the code:

```
void func(int x)
{
    int a = x;
    int b = 0;  // set a breakpoint
}

int main()
{
    func(10);  // set a breakpoint
    return 0;
}
```

Then I use gdb to get its assembly:

`main`:

[image]

`func`:

[image]

Now we can see that there is no return address being saved in the two function stacks (at least this is my view).

If a hacker wants to hack this program with stack smashing, which address in the function stack will be edited illegally by him?

Comment: On x86 architecture, the `call` instruction puts the return address on the stack. On other architectures, the equivalent instruction might put it into a register and the callee can then save that on the stack if necessary.

Comment: @Jester   "the `call` instruction puts the return address on the stack" --- is it possible to see this in the two images? I just want to see the real address like 0x00001234.

Comment: No, the value is on the stack. You can see it e.g. by doing `x/a $rsp` right after the `callq` (i.e. at the entry to `func`, address `0x400687`).

Comment: But your screenshots do not show the content of the stack at all. What exactly are you trying to demonstrate by these? Why are you looking at the code instead of looking at the stack?

Comment: What Jester wrote plus check the value of `rsp` before/after `call` ("print $rsp" I guess in gdb?) to see how it did `rsp-=8` (in same fashion as `push rax` would change it). "stack" memory is like any other regular memory, and `rsp` is almost like any other register, all the "stack" magic is just that the `push/pop/call/ret/leave/enter/..` instructions use `rsp` value as pointer into memory implicitly. I.e. `push rax` is almost equal to `sub rsp,8` `mov [rsp],rax`, it's just sort of more atomic, and doesn't affect flags. (and "stack smashing" = changing memory content around `rsp` address).

Comment: @AnT  My screenshots doesn't show the content of the stack at all? So what can I do to show the content of the stack? The screenshots came from the command of gdb: `disassemble`. I thought this could show the stack... Well, I just want to know all of details of stack. This is why I have such a question.

Comment: @Yves: No, they don't. Your screenshots show *code*. Meanwhile, the term "stack" refers to the special region in program's *data* memory. It stores *data*: typically it's local variables, temporary objects, *return addresses*, intermediate internal values that need to be dumped to memory temporarily and other stuff like that. Jester's comment above already told you what you have to do in order to make gdb to display the current contents of the *stack*. Also, if you do `backtrace` in gdb, it will show you the current call context built specifically from the return address stored in the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now we can see that there is no return address being saved in the two function stacks (at least this is my view).

What you are actually showing is the *disassembled code*, not the stack.

The return address is pushed on the stack by the *caller* by means of  the `callq` instruction. At the moment of entering the *callee* function it is at the top of the stack, i.e.: at that moment, `rsp` contains the address where the *return address* is stored.

---

#### Inspecting the stack with GDB

- `p/x $rsp` displays the value of the `rsp` register, i.e.: the *address* of the top of the stack, since `rsp` *points* to the top of the stack.
- `x/x $rsp` displays the memory contents located at the top of stack (i.e.: the contents located at the address pointed by `rsp`).

With this information in mind you can run the command `x/x $rsp` at the moment of entering the callee function (before anything else is pushed onto the stack) to obtain the return address.

You can also use the command `info frame` to inspect the current *stack frame*. The displayed field with the name `saved rip` corresponds to the current function's return address. However, you need to run this command after the stack frame for the current function has been created and before it is destroyed (i.e.: after `mov %rsp,%rbp` but before `pop %rbp` inside the callee).

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie on this. I just used the command of gdb: `disassemble` to get the screenshots. So if I want to show the stack, what can I do?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is.  Examine the stack immediately before the `callq` and immediately after it.  You will find that the address of the instruction following the `callq` now appears on the top of the stack and RSP has decremented by 8.

The `callq` instruction causes the address of the following instruction to be pushed onto the stack.  Inversely, the `retq` instruction at the end of the function causes the address on the stack to be popped into the `RIP`.

Comment: You mean `RSP` and `8` :)

Comment: Can you show me which lines of instruction in the images should I notice?

Comment: @Yves : The [CALL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) instruction is what places the return address on the top of the stack.

Comment: @jester Absolutely :). I've been in the 32 bit world this week.